# Insertion of duplicate keys on mySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, insert

How would I insert new fields even if the field is a duplicate of my primary key.

I have 6 fields in my table - Employee_Number, Week_number, Time_in, Time_out, Hours, Overtime
Employee_number, week_number and day make up a composite key.

I have just noticed that if the the employee (500456) clocked in on week number 4 on a Monday, they wouldn't be able to clock in on Tuesday of the same week. Is there an SQL statement I can use to fix this?

This is what I currently have;

```
"INSERT INTO daily_calculations (EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, WEEK_NUMBER, DAY, TIME_IN, TIME_OUT, HOURS, OVERTIME)"
sqlquery2 = sqlquery2 + "VALUES ('" & ENumber & "','" & WeekNum & "', '" & day & "', '" & StartTime & "', '" & EndTime & "',"
sqlquery2 = sqlquery2 + "'" & Hours & "', '" & Overtime & "');"
```

Comment: Why not include `DAY` in your composite key? That would make each key unique, right?

Comment: My mistake, It is part of the composite key

Comment: I think your premise is wrong. Monday and Tuesday are different days in the same week, and since DAY is part of your key, the "Tuesday" insert will not fail.

Comment: Sorry I made a really stupid mistake. My database table has so around 200 fields, I lost track. Just realized that Tuesday for that employee is already inserted.

Comment: I'm wondering why the use of unique keys at all. Sure, the `employee_number` should be unique, but the rest, no. For example, an employee may clock in and out multiple times in a day. How is that going to work?

Comment: To be honest, that should be taken into consideration. But this is just a little project for school .. So I think for now i'll just leave it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `INSERT IGNORE...`

> If you use the `IGNORE` keyword, errors that occur while executing the `INSERT` statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without `IGNORE`, a row that duplicates an existing `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY` value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With `IGNORE`, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Comment: That's not what I want though, If it were to ignore it no error would come up but the entry still won't be inserted. So then If the employee had clocked in on Monday then the rest of the week won't be inserted. I think, or am i wrong?